# $\mathrm{MI}(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{x}) = 0$ if $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}$ are orthogonal

Tags: mutual-information

Let $\mathbf{a}, \mathbf{b} \in \mathbb{R}^N$ be two orthogonal vectors, and $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^N$ a random vector variable with some probability density function.

Prove or disprove that, as a consequence of the orthogonality of $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}$:

$$\mathrm{MI}(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{x}) = 0$$

where MI stands for mutual information.

Comment: related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/438613/5536, https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/492232/5536

Comment: What applications are there for multiplying a *univariate* dataset by an orthogonal vector? I only know of applications for *multivariate* dataset $\mathbf{X}$

Comment: @develarist Why do you say x is univariate?

Comment: Because you yourself said it's a random vector variable

Comment: @develarist I did not meat to say it was univariate.

Comment: oh ok, maybe you should edit then. *a* random variable is different than *many* random variables

Comment: You can have *a* random variable that lives in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: to me, $\mathbb{R}^n$ is still univariate, whereas $\mathbb{R}^{t\times n}$ would be multivariate time series. My notation doesn't hide what's "living in"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Counter-example:

Let $\mathbf{x} = (x_1,x_2)$, $\mathbf{a} = (1,0)$ and $\mathbf{b} = (0,1)$

Then

$$\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{x} = x_1$$
$$\mathbf{b} \cdot \mathbf{x} = x_2$$

and

$$\mathrm{MI}(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{x}) = \mathrm{MI}(x_1,x_2)$$

If in addition the components $x_1$ and $x_2$ have mutual information (for instance they could be correlated) then also $\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{x}$ have mutual information and $\mathrm{MI}(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{x}) \neq 0$.

Comment: Ok, I had the wrong intuition here. Thanks for the easy counter-example.

Comment: It is maybe somewhat similar to [Is it possible for two random variables to be negatively correlated, but both be positively correlated with a third r.v.?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/495546/) in terms of intuition.

Comment: Can we find another counter-example, where the density of $\mathbf{x}$ is not singular?

Comment: @becko I have adjusted my answer to cover your comment.

Comment: Thanks. That covers it.