# Mutual Information between Gaussians in the limiting, strongly correlated case

Tags: information-theory, mutual-information

In [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/438607/mutual-information-between-subsets-of-variables-in-the-multivariate-normal-distr) it is derived that if X, Y are correlated Gaussian variables, the mutual information between them is given by

$$ I(X;Y) = \log\left(\frac{\det(\Sigma_X)\det(\Sigma_Y)}{\det\Sigma_{XY}}\right) $$

where $\Sigma_X,\Sigma_Y,\Sigma_{XY}$ denote the covariance matrices of X, Y and X,Y jointly, respectively.

Now, consider the system

$$ X = U + Nx, Y = U + Ny $$

where $U, Nx, Ny$ are univariate Gaussians and independent from each other. Further, assume the variance of Nx, Ny are both equal $\sigma_n^2$. Then,

$$\Sigma_{XY} = [[\sigma_n^2+\sigma_u^2, \sigma_u^2], [\sigma_u^2, \sigma_n^2+\sigma_u^2]]$$

Hence, the mutual information is given by

$$ I(X;Y) = \log\frac{(\sigma_u^2+\sigma_n^2)^2}{\sigma_n^4+2\sigma_n^2\sigma_u^2} $$

Now, if we let $\sigma_n\rightarrow 0$, i.e. $X$, $Y$ become more and more correlated, the expression above blows up to infinity. However, the expected result in the limit (when $\sigma_n=0$) is $I(X;Y)=I(U;U)=H(U)=\log\sigma_u^2$.

I suppose $I$ as a function of $\sigma_n$ should be continuous, and hence for small noise terms it should not grow to large values. In particular, for small $\sigma_n$, $I$ can grow above $H(U)$ which is impossible in reality.

Where is my fault?

Comment: Gaussian distribution has $\sigma^2 > 0$, so you should not expect anything to hold if it is not met. Also if the variables are constant, they cannot be correlated, so you should not use the formula for correlated variables.

Comment: thanks! Also, for $\sigma_n\rightarrow0$ the expression blows up to infinity, where the system itself is well-defined. I expect that $I$ as a function of $\sigma_n$ is continuous, hence it cannot blow up to infinity for small noise terms.

Comment: I'm lost, are you asking about the limit or the degenerate case where it *is* zero?

Comment: I believe that due to continuity reasons, the limit should lead to the degenerate case. Therefore, I'm looking at the Gaussian case expression and let the noise degrade to zero. So, I'm asking about the limit.

Comment: Could you then edit your question "degenerate case" $\to$ "limiting case" and "$\sigma_n = 0$" $\to$ "$\sigma_n \to 0$"?

Comment: I have changed the title and reformatted the question.